# Getting motor speed from motor driver

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, driver

I am trying to read speed from a motor driver to a rpi. As i wish to make a PID controller
using

I am using the following driver
http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/md49tech.htm#speed

```py
import serial 
import struct 

#Currently i am setting the speed as following, works fine
def SET_SPEED_1(speed):
    strSpeed = struct.pack("B",speed)
    writeBytes("\x00\x31" + strSpeed)

#And i read the encoder as follows
def GET_ENCODER_1():
    writeBytes("\x00\x23")
    encByte = struct.unpack("B",port.read())
    encByte += struct.unpack("B",port.read())
    encByte += struct.unpack("B",port.read())
    encByte += struct.unpack("B",port.read())
    encoder = (encByte[0] << 24) + (encByte[1] << 16) + (encByte[2] << 8) + encByte[3]
    return encoder
```

the commands are sent with a sync byte of 0 at the start and then the command followed by any data bytes

So i want to read speed but cant get it to work

```
def GET_SPEED_1():   
    writeBytes("\x00\x21")
    speed = struct.unpack("B", port.read())
```

but i get an output saying "none"
I am not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: before trying to unpack, are you sure when you do `port.read()` that you are receiving anything? Is the microcontroller indeed responding to the commands you send and returning you data? Once you are sure you receive something you can try to unpack it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question to make it a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example you don't show how you have setup `port` or what `writeBytes` does. It would also help if you showed the full stacktrace. Where are you getting the `None` from? Maybe store the `port.read()` into a variable so you can print it out.